# Rearranging the keys in a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, key, handlebars.js

I have a JSON in which keys are in following order:

```
var JSON= {"code" :1, "country": "US", "node": 1, "region": "abc, "time": 34};
```

Now this JSON is passed to a Handlebars template which parses it and puts these values in a table in the same order as the keys.

I want to shuffle the order of the keys so that instead of the order that is there in JSON, the keys can get accessed in this order:

```
node, time, region, code, country
```

Is there anyway in Javascript that we can alter the order of the keys?

Comment: no  Javascript objects properties are unordered by definition; so sorting them is meaningless.

Comment: You made the statement, "the keys can get accessed in this order." You can access keys in that order in a function. Or, if you want a JSON string in that order you could build it manually with a function as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Object keys don't assure a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order),

but if you know the keys you can map it directly:

```js
var o = {
    "code": 1,
    "country": "US",
    "node": 1,
    "region": "abc",
    "time": 34
};

var order = ['node', 'time', 'region', 'code', 'country']

var res = order.map( x => o[x] )

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Though this works is not really changed the order of the original object but the copy of the object created by map under the new "rule".